# Display overflown content in ngx-datatable

Tags: html, css, tooltip, ngx-datatable

I'm using ngx-datatable to render a table with infinite scroll. I also need to ad a tooltip on each row with some extra data. 
My problem is that the absolute positioned tooltip renders beneath the lower rows even though I've set `overflow: visible;` to all the parents and also the tooltip has a `z-index: 9999;`. 
The tooltip is positioned absolute while the row is relative.

Desired outcome:
[image: Desired outcome]

Actual outcome:
[image: actual outcome]

Is there any way that I could force the tooltip to render above anything else?

**Edit**: I should also mention that the tooltip has a white background, but the row is transparent. If I set the row's background to anything, the tooltip won't be visible anymore beyond the first row.

Comment: Don't forget to set `position` different from `static` when use z-index.

Comment: the tooltip has `absolute` and the row has `relative`, i'll edit the question. thanks